# Supporting Multiple Screens with size qualifier

Tags: android

We would like to design layouts for specific resolutions as below:

Samsung Duos: 480 X 800 Android Version 4.0.4
HTC Velocity: 540 X 960

To do so we have created layout folders for each as below:

layout-w480dp-h800dp
layout-w540dp-h960dp

Assuming that if we run application on samsung duaos it should pick the layouts from 
layout-w480dp-h800dp folder but it is giving error and unable to start activity.

The error is:

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030029

It means it could not locate the layout required by the activity. Same happen with HTC Velocity.

Are we doing something wrong?

Please let us know if you have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

must have been a problem with some resource try to delete a image file from drawable and add it again build the project it should run

Comment: Actually we have verified R.java for the "Resource ID #0x7f030029" and found it is talking about the layout file.

Comment: have you tried what I said ?, believe me as a trainer I always say "Never trust Eclipse" .

Comment: Yes, but got the same result

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to Clean and Build? It usually help as looks like R generation was corrupted

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is wrong.
layout-w480dp-h800dp isn't for 480x800 px screen.
DP is way Different than PX. Please read this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.

Are you sure you really need different designs for so similar handsets? I would say this is pointless.

In my opinion at most U should distinguish 3 types of devices.

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

If you still want to do what you are trying to do you can try px instead of dp. But Im not sure if this will work ...

Comment: Mark, we got your point but would like to consider the height as well

Comment: Are you doing your application only for these 2 devices? If yes and you really want to distinguish them calculations of px to dp should work. Just remember that when screen has 800px height - the real workspace for activity is smaller because of system bars. When answer to my question is NO. Change your design then - These 2 devices should have the same layout and you just need to use dp, weights etc properly.

Comment: We have tried with res/layout-sw480dp/activity_home.xml and execute the application on Samsung duos but the result is same.

Comment: Let me explain, as you know that the android devices are available with different dimensions. Our home screen is designed in such a way that it should fit or cover the whole screen. To do so, we have started with motorolla 320 x 480 and set the layout accordingly, then go for Samsung Duos, here width is not issue but need to scale up the resources by height, so we have prepared graphics for the same, but our application should know that if it is running on motorolla then pick layout from "layout" folder and if Samsung Duos then layout-<someidentifier>. But none of the idea is working still.

Comment: Ok .. so now Im quite sure that your design is wrong :) now you will fix the size for Samsung Duos and later you will have problems with HTC desire / HTC One / Galaxy S I,II,III. When you say that you had to "prepare graphics" specially for Samsung Duos it means design of your application is wrong for Android. You should use nine patches as graphics, use Imageviews with fitCenter/CenterInside, use gradient drawables built in xml etc. When you design your app and you will have to provide graphics for all screens which differ 100px - good luck then :P

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a default layout that relate to your activity?I mean each folder containing the layout of the same name.

Comment: No, we are trying to design layouts for Samsung Duos and HTC Velocity by defining layout folder along with size tag. We also tried the same by converting pixel to dp meaning for 480 X 800 resolution it is layout-2720dp-h1200dp, but got the same result.

Comment: You are still trying to do something strange... How is it possible that 2720dp would be your size of the screen (4inch HTC), when google says that 720dp is 10 inch screen. ?!